# Horizontal coordinate adjustment using EPSG 9621 operation method in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, epsg, postgis-raster, cartesian

We have some Cartesian coordinates which needs to be applied with similarity transformation. The transformation operation method describing how to do the same is explained in EPSG 9621 method.

How to I use this method directly in PostGIS function? How to apply this transformation as I have the values of those parameters?

Comment: Technically this is a simplification of an orthogonal transformation, or a specific case of a change of basis in linear algebra; you should be able to apply its matrix form with `ST_Affine`. Note that the `proj` library powering `ST_Transform` short circuits to using affine transformations if given suitable source and target CRS.

Comment: I want to do this to a PostGIS raster grid and not to a vector geometry data. Any idea?

Comment: You can `ST_Transform` rasters? Are you working with supported CRS?

Comment: CRS like proj4 will support datum,projection and 7/3 param transforms. The affine transform of 9621 is slightly different not sure how i can accomodate that one.

Comment: To add more it is custom CRS and not public known CRS